# Channel not being connected when trying to enable one on one chat in Stream (JS)

Tags: getstream-io

I have an app I'm building where one user (called admin) has a one on one channel with most users. My understanding is that only one channel will exist when I create a one on one chat, regardless of who (admin or user) creates it first. My issue is that when I add a user and a new one on one chat should be established, other channels are being duplicated in my channel list as well. Either that, or sometimes the channel just doesn't connect at all, and the user is left without a chat. The code/pseudo-code I am using is below, does anyone know how to create multiple one on one chats using stream, or why certain channels might be connecting twice?

P.S. I'm editing the code to simplify it to only relevant parts here on stack overflow, so please ignore any simple syntax errors below. Thanks!

```
  setupUserChats = async (chatClient) => {
    let { currentUser, participants } = this.props;


    if (the current user is an admin) {

      for (let i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
        let participant = participants[i];
        
        if (if the participant is a user) {
          
          let conversation = await chatClient.channel('messaging', {
            name: participant.name,
            members: [`${currentUser.participant_id}`, `${participant.participant_id}`]
          });

          await conversation.watch();
        }
      }
    }

    if (currentUser is a user) {

      for (let i = 0; i < participants.length; i++) {
        let participant = participants[i];

        if (participant is an admin) {

          let conversation = await chatClient.channel('messaging', {
            name: currentUser.name,
            members: [`${currentUser.participant_id}`, `${participant.participant_id}`]
          });

          await conversation.watch();

        }
      }
    }

    this.setState({ chatClient: chatClient });

  }
```

I call another function (outlined below) to set up the basic chat, and then call the above code inside of this next function:

```
  setupChat = async () => {
    let { currentUser, participants } = this.props;

    let chatClient = await new StreamChat(process.env.REACT_APP_STREAM_API_KEY);
    let serverResult = await getStreamToken(currentUser.participant_id);
    let userToken = serverResult.token;

    await chatClient.setUser(
      {
        id: currentUser.participant_id,
        name: currentUser.name,
      },
      userToken,
    );



    const moderatorToAdmin = await chatClient.channel('messaging', `conference-ID`, {
      name: "moderator-chat"
    });


    await moderatorToAdmin.watch();


    this.setupUserChats(chatClient);



    moderatorToAdmin.addMembers([`${currentUser.participant_id}`]);
        
    this.setState({ chatClient: chatClient });
  };
```

And then its all rendered here:

```
  render() {
    const { currentUser } = this.props;

    const filters = { members: { $in: [currentUser.participant_id] } }
    
    return (
      <div>
          <Chat client={this.state.chatClient} theme={'messaging light'} >
            <div className="title">Chat</div>
              <ChannelList
                filters={filters}
                Preview={MyChannelPreview}
              />
            <Channel Message={MyMessageComponent} >
              <Window>
                <MessageList />
                <MessageInput />
              </Window>
              <Thread />
            </Channel>
          </Chat>
      </div>
    );

  }




class MyChannelPreview extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const { setActiveChannel, channel } = this.props;

    return (
      <div className={`channel_preview` + currentChannelClass}>
        <a href="#" onClick={(e) => setActiveChannel(channel, e)}>
          {channel._data.name || channel.data.name}
        </a>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```